# Django Rest Framework add class level method to api

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Rest Framework to create my API. I am using @link to return information about a particular object.

```
class SomeClassView(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
   @link
   def info(self, request, pk=None):
       obj = models.SomeClass.objects.get(pk=pk)
       return Response({"info": object.info()})

 GET: /someclass/1/info
```

What I would like to do is extend the method so I can access it at the "class level" so that my api could accept a list of objects

```
class SomeClassView(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
   @link
   def info(self, request, pk=None):
       if isinstance(s, str):
           obj = models.SomeClass.objects.get(pk=pk)
           return Response({"info": obj.info()})
       else:
           objs = models.SomeClass.objects.filter(pk__in=pk).all()
           return Response({"infos": [obj.info() for obj in objs]})

GET: /someclass/1/info
GET: /someclass/info?pk=1&pk=2&pk=3
```

Is there a way I can add a class level method to my api? Or will I need to create a new class to handle the one api call?

PS: I don't mind if I need to have a separate method to make this work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dynamically generated routes using the `@link` or `@action` decorators are hard-coded to look like `/someclass/<pk>/<methodname>/`.  You can expose a `/someclass/info` endpoint by adding a custom route, e.g.:

```
class MyRouter(DefaultRouter):
    routes = [
        Route(
            url=r'^{prefix}/((?P<pk>\d+)/)?info$',
            mapping={'get': 'info'},
            name='{basename}-info',
            initkwargs={}
        )
    ] + DefaultRouter.routes
```

Then your `info` method might look like this:

```
def info(self, request, pk=None):
    if pk:
        obj = SomeClass.objects.get(pk=pk)
        return Response({'info': obj.info()})
    else:
        objs = SomeClass.objects.filter(pk__in=request.GET.getlist('pk'))
        return Response({'infos': [obj.info() for obj in objs]})
```

(Note the absence of the `@link` decorator.)

Comment: I was afraid of that. I would have liked the final solution to have been part of the class.