# django-rest defaultRouter doesn't add @action

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am reading http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers#usage and can't understand what a base_name is. Also i try to add a custom action and the router won't pick it up

I have this views.py

```
@authentication_classes((SessionAuthentication, TokenAuthentication))
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))  
class utente(CreateModelMixin, RetrieveAPIView, GenericViewSet, ViewSet):

    model = MyUser
    serializer_class = MyUserSerializer

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = MyUser.objects.get(
           pk = request.user.pk
        )
        serializer = MyUserSerializerGET(self.object)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    @action(permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated])#POST action    
    def customaction(self, request):
        return Response( None )
        pass
```

and this urls.py

```
admin.autodiscover()


router_v1 = routers.DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=True)
router_v1.register(r'register', my_register, 'wtf' )
router_v1.register(r'utente', utente, 'wtf2' )
#router_v1.register(r'utente/customaction', utente.as_view({'post' : 'customaction'})   )

api_urls_v1 = router_v1.urls

api_urls = patterns('',
    url(r'^v1/', include(api_urls_v1)),
)  

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'wecup.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^login/', 'rest_framework.authtoken.views.obtain_auth_token'), 
    url(r'^logout/', my_logout ), 
    url(r'^api/', include(api_urls)), 
)
```

when i open `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/`

```
HTTP 200 OK Content-Type: application/json Vary: Accept Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
{
    "register": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/register/", 
    "utente": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/utente/"



     where is customaction?
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You've got two different questions here, so I'll address them each separately.

### Base Name

First, a `base_name` is simply the name the `ViewSet` will use when generating your named urls. By default, this will simply be your `model` or perhaps your `queryset`, though you may need to set it automatically if you've played with your `ViewSet`'s `get_queryset` method.

If you don't implement your own url names, then the `base_name` will be used to implement them for you. For example, given that your `Model` is `MyUser`, your named urls would be something like `'myuser-list'` or `'myuser-detail'`.

Documentation, if interested, is [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers#usage).

### @action and custom methods

You're using a `DefaultRouter`, which allows you to access the API root view at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/`, as you've shown. This root view only shows **list views.** Using `@action` creates a **detail view**. In your case, your `customaction` view can be found at `^utente/{pk}/customaction/$`. **It will not show up in the API root because it is not a list view.**

General information on `@action` and custom methods can be found [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets#marking-extra-methods-for-routing).

Also, if for some reason you **do** want to make `customaction` a list-level view, you'll need to make some modifications. You could either string up a custom route yourself, without using the `@action` decorator (which is specifically for detail views). An example of that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19106201/django-rest-framework-add-class-level-method-to-api).

Your other option is to use the new-ish [drf-extensions](https://github.com/chibisov/drf-extensions) package. A discussion of using the package to implement collection level controllers in ViewSets can be found [here](http://chibisov.github.io/drf-extensions/docs/#collection-level-controllers).

Comment: drf-extension #action(is_for_list=True) doesn't shows up in api list, customaction doesn't help either and what is a base_name for ?

Comment: I haven't used drf-extension too much, so perhaps it won't add it to your api root. Just to check--did you mean @action (instead of #action as you typed)? If it doesn't add it, then you'll just need to use the other method if you want it there.

Regarding base_name, are you familiar with url `name`s? Documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns). Basically, naming urls allows for looser-coupling in your app, so you can change your url pattern easily. The `base_name` attribute helps generate named urls for the urls in your `ViewSet`.